# Uploading Audio Files with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: audio, file, asihttprequest, uploading

Can anyone please give me a tutorial on how to upload Audio Files onto a server using ASIHTTPRequest? 
I'll need to build a JSON and get the audio data into the JSON then send it to the server. If this is too vague please don't hesitate to ask for more info.

let's say i use AVAudioRecorder class. What would i use to send that audio file to the server that is created after I record it and am ready to upload it?

Comment: When you say you want to upload "audio data" are you talking about the song bits?  If so then don't encode with JSON!

Comment: I'll post an edit to give people a clearer meaning

Answer (score 0):

You would use the ASIFormDataRequest class. See the "Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest" section of this url: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

You may need to temporarily store the file on the phone, get the path to that file, and then sent it as a file in this class. It works with images I know, so it should work with other files as well. Your PHP script or whatever that is receiving the file will just need to know how to handle the file type.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Comment: do you think ASIHTTP would work for streaming as well?  or this answer/suggestion would be for uploading a finished audio file?